# SELECT command denied to user 'not showing user :)' for table 'users'

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the error:

```
SELECT command denied to user 'notshowinguser :)' for table 'users'
```

When I'm trying to log into my website. I am using GoDaddy.

The log in system is working on my localhost.

Is there any way I could give all of my users access to log in without having to grant it to them individually?

Comment: If you need to see any code, just ask : )

Comment: You only have two or three users - 'user' simply denotes the level of access - administrator, guest, etc

Comment: sounds like `'notshowinguser :)'` doesn't have permission to do that on the database.

Comment: ^ If that is the case, how could I edit it so it has permission to do that? (I'm new with databases and I am 13 years old)

Comment: @user3416605 not sure how your connecting to your db but here is all you can do with users: [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-account-management.html)